# Cropping axis tick labels when exporting figures

Tags: matlab, figures

The are entries suggesting the usage of `export_fig` package for exporting figures from MATLAB. However, when I use `export_fig` without any `xlabel`, the output figure has the x-tick labels trimmed from the bottom. With `xlabel` there are no problems. Am I doing something wrong here or have you also faced this problem?

I am attaching two figures and an example code.

Thanks,

[image: bottom of the figure cropped]

[image: bottom of the figure not cropped]

```
observeCropped = 1;
t = 0:.001:2;
f = @(t) sin(2*pi*t);
plot(t, f(t));
title('sin(t)');
if observeCropped
    export_fig sin1.pdf
else
    xlabel('time');
    export_fig sin2.pdf
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem. It's work correct. If you want x-tick label without trimming try this code:

```
observeCropped = 1;
t = 0:.001:2;
f = sin(2*pi*t);
plot(t, f(t));
title('sin(t)');
xlabel('    ');
if observeCropped
    export_fig sin1.pdf
else
    export_fig sin2.pdf
end
```

:)

Comment: Oh I see. Well this adds maybe a bit too much space but can be removed by external tools, while trimming cannot be.